# Custom password encryption fails when updating other than pw in backend

Tags: encryption, typo3, backend, password-encryption, typo3-7.6.x

**I have following situation:**

The existing users have been stored and maintained in a 3rd party software fully which uses a different password encryption than provided by saltedpasswords. The new website which will be built with TYPO3 should be used for user management in future. As the data needs to be stored in the 3rd party software as well, we cannot simply renew them on login. *They are needed because of an API for certificate requests. So, just some data are moved to TYPO3 yet.*

Whatsoever, nothing special yet. I added a new salt method which is basically working in following scenarios:

- Create a new user via BE
- Create a new user via FE (*EXT:femanager*)
- Update an existing user's PW via BE
- Update an existing user data via FE (*EXT:femanager*)

In following scenario it does not work:

- When updating any data but the password via BE => the password is renewed and begins with an "M".

Is there a specific configuration or hook needed for that?

I appreciate any hint. Thanks in advance

Best regards,

AMartinNo1

Answer (score -1):

**temporary solution:**

*The 3rd party software containing users is self-hosted and protected by firewalls. So, as a first step we will use the same mechanism - md5-hashes.*

EXT:saltedpasswords checks in `TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Evaluation\Evaluator::evaluateFieldValue($value, $is_in, &$set` whether `$value` is a simple hash and hashes with the respective `SaltFactory` again plus prefix it with `M`.

Until we switch to an improved password encryption mechanism (needs adjustments in the 3rd party software as well) I simply comment the "double hashing" out in the sysext-core-method. So that we continue with devleoping other functions.

*Of course we change the 3rd party software (replace or update) before go-live, so that we can make usage of a proper password encryption.*

Comment: This is not secure, you are putting your users at risk because of development issues! Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: As I said, it's just during dev. Before go live is going to be changed.

Comment: So you are spending time on an interim security solution that will be replaced later, seems like a waste of effort. Interesting how security comes last and we are having so many security failures. correlation? It would seem getting the security in early is not a project impact unless ...  So the issue is benefit, getting a product out and generation money is a benefit for the company, security is a benefit for the users. The dilemma: which to focus on—oh wait, we have the answer to that.

Comment: In the first place it was easier to develop a custom salt which itself was done within a few minutes. Yes, in the end it took more time but that's because TYPO3 performs this md5-check we was not aware of before. And, I never said that this is going to be released. We migrate user data, we can test with real data whether UI etc. is working and in the meantime we work on the password-encryption.

Comment: In General password and encryption should not be used together, note that hashing is not encryption. PHP has secure and simple to use password hashing: `password_hash` and `password_verify` and it is arguable that using them is easier than a hash solution. If you "world a better place for next generations" put security first.

Comment: It is, because otherwise we have to modify the 3rd party software in terms of registration, user data update and more. So yes, there is an effort behind that which we would like to do while we can test the new system with real data already. So, why not importing the data and let testers test with real data and in the meantime the security stuff is updated.

Comment: There is always a reason to put off security, it is after all a PITA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147735/discussion-between-amartinno1-and-zaph).

Comment: There is nothing to continue: I put security first, you don't.